# The users/{id}/timeline method is returning an extra result.

Tags: bug, status-completed

The users/{id}/timeline method is returning 31 results by default, and one more result than specified by the `pagesize` parameter.

Example:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1288/timeline?pagesize=1

API Help: http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users/{id}/timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.  Silly off by 1 errors.